# Filtering a large dataframe in pandas using multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nodes, traversal

I have a dataframe and I need to filter it according to the following conditions

```
CITY == 'Mumbai' & LANGUAGE == 'English' & GENRE == 'ACTION' & count_GENRE >= 1
CITY == 'Mumbai' & LANGUAGE == 'English' & GENRE == 'ROMANCE' & count_GENRE >= 1
CITY == 'Mumbai' & LANGUAGE == 'Hindi' & count_LANGUAGE >= 1 & GENRE == 'ACTION'
```

when I am trying to do that by

```
  df1 = df.query(condition1)
  df2 = df.query(condition2)
```

I am getting memory error(since my dataframe size is Huge).

SO I planned to go by filtering main condition then sub condition, so that the load will be less and performance will be better.

By parsing above conditions, somehow managed to get

```
main_filter = "CITY == 'Mumbai'"
sub_cond1 = "LANGUAGE == 'English'"
sub_cond1_cond1 = "GENRE == 'ACTION' & count_GENRE >= 1"
sub_cond1_cond2 = "GENRE == 'ROMANCE' & count_GENRE >= 1"
sub_cond2 = "LANGUAGE == 'Hindi' & count_LANGUGE >= 1"
sub_cond2_cond1 = "GENRE == 'COMEDY'"
```

So think it as a tree structure(not binary of course and actually it is not a tree at all).

Now I want to follow a multiprocessing method (deep -- sub process under subprocess)

Now I want something like

```
on level 1
 df = df_main.query(main_filter)
on level 2
 df1 = df.query(sub_cond1)
 df2 = df.query(sub_cond2)
onlevel 3
  df11 = df1.query(sub_cond1_cond1)
  df12 = df1.query(sub_cond1_cond2)
  df21 = df2.query(sub_cond2_cond1)  ######like this
```

So problem is how to pass conditions properly to each level(if I am going to store all conditions in a list(Actually not even thought about that)).

NB: result from each filteration should export to separate separate csvs.

Ex:

```
df11.to_csv('CITY == 'Mumbai' & LANGUAGE == 'English' & GENRE == 'ACTION' & count_GENRE >= 1')
```

As a starter I don't know how to follow multiprocessing (its syntax & way of execution, etc particularly for this). But got the task unfortunately. Hence not able to post any codes.

So can anybody give a codeline example to achieve this.

If you have any better idea (class object or node traversing), please suggest.

Comment: What does "huge" mean? Do you have a number? e.g. memory size or rows*cols in the dataframe?

Comment: @SteveMisuta-Actually it contains 160 mln records appx. and and i have to run 2 3 more .py files at a time which are accessing that dataframe  internally and simultaneously.That's where i am getting memory error(out of RAM capacity). ANd i can't do anything about that(separately running alll those py files)

Comment: @SteveMisuta-if you have any idea like list iteration way,then checking first char(if startswith sub_ or sub_cond1    like this).Then also i am fine with that.please  suggest.

Comment: If you are reading the data into memory from a file then maybe take look at using a chunking technique to read in smaller sections and process/output each section sequentially. The pandas read_csv method has chunks and iterator keyword arguments for sequentially reading in subsets of the main dataset. Since you are not doing any grouping but only filtering, you can process the entire dataset sequentially. Example: divide the dataset into N chunks, read each one in, do your filtering, write csv files, delete dataframes in memory, read next chunk, filter, append output to the csv files, etc.

Comment: See the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking

Comment: @SteveMisuta-That technique i have already used(not helpful in my case),but the thing is my processing is based on datetime(a column) field and the dependency is like i need the whole data as a unit for processing.BTW respect your suggestion.

Answer (score 21):

This looks like a problem suitable for [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html#), the python module that helps you deal with larger-than-memory data.

I will show how to solve this problem using the `dask.dataframe`. Let's start by creating some data:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple
Record = namedtuple('Record', "CITY LANGUAGE GENRE count_GENRE count_LANGUAGE")

cities = ['Mumbai', 'Chennai', 'Bengalaru', 'Kolkata']
languages = ['English', 'Hindi', 'Spanish', 'French']
genres = ['Action', 'Romance', 'Comedy', 'Drama']

import random

df = pd.DataFrame([Record(random.choice(cities), 
                          random.choice(languages), 
                          random.choice(genres), 
                          random.choice([1,2,3]), 
                          random.choice([1,2,3])) for i in range(4000000)])

df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)    
print(df.head())

        CITY LANGUAGE    GENRE  count_GENRE  count_LANGUAGE
0    Chennai  Spanish   Action            2               1
1  Bengalaru  English    Drama            2               3
2    Kolkata  Spanish   Action            2               1
3     Mumbai   French  Romance            1               2
4    Chennai   French   Action            2               3
```

The data created above has 4 million rows, and occupies 107 MB.   It is not larger-than-memory,  but good enough to use in this example.

Below I show the transcript of a `python` session where I filtered the data according to the criteria in the question:

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> dask_df = dd.read_csv('temp.csv', header=0)
>>> dask_df.npartitions
4

# We see above that dask.dataframe has decided to split the 
# data into 4 partitions

# We now execute the query:
>>> result = dask_df[(dask_df['CITY'] == 'Mumbai') &
...                  (dask_df['LANGUAGE'] == 'English') &
...                  (dask_df['GENRE'] == 'Action') &
...                  (dask_df['count_GENRE'] > 1)]
>>>

# The line above takes very little time to execute.  In fact, nothing has
# really been computed yet.  Behind the scenes dask has create a plan to  
# execute the query, but has not yet pulled the trigger.

# The result object is a dask dataframe:
>>> type(result)
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
>>> result
dd.DataFrame<series-slice-read-csv-temp.csv-fc62a8c019c213f4cd106801b9e45b29[elemwise-cea80b0dd8dd29ae325a9db1896b027c], divisions=(None, None, None, None, None)>

# We now pull the trigger by calling the compute() method on the dask
# dataframe.  The execution of the line below takes a few seconds:
>>> dfout = result.compute()

# The result is a regular pandas dataframe:
>>> type(dfout)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

# Of our 4 million records, only ~40k match the query:
>>> len(dfout)
41842

>>> dfout.head()
       CITY LANGUAGE   GENRE  count_GENRE  count_LANGUAGE
225  Mumbai  English  Action            2               3
237  Mumbai  English  Action            3               2
306  Mumbai  English  Action            3               3
335  Mumbai  English  Action            2               2
482  Mumbai  English  Action            2               3
```

I hope this gets you started on the solution to your problem.  For more info on `dask` see the [tutorial](https://github.com/blaze/dask-tutorial) and [examples](https://github.com/blaze/dask-examples).

Comment: @Pedro-thanks for a new approach.I have not tested your example yet.But how much (appx.) time it took  to filter out from 4 mln records.

Comment: @Satya `In [6]: %time dfout = result.compute()
Wall time: 5.05 s`

Comment: @Satya, `dask` actually uses `multiprocessing`,  so you will see some speedup if you have more than one core

Comment: @Pedro-on a personal note,can you suggest me on(my dataframe has 160+millions record with 135 columns ).And if i go by filtering whole 1 condition line (like the condition for 'result' in your code) one by one.Then for each condition i am picking the dataframe completely and filtering by long condition.So in dask can it give me a performance???? or the way i suggested ,in each time/level reducing the dataframe size by filtering on a small condition(main filter,sub-filter) will be considerable.

Comment: @Satya you have a situation where the various queries have some common conditions.   If a subset of the common conditions are sufficient to bring the size of the results to something reasonable, then the best approach would be to 1. Use `dask` to filter by the smallest subset of common conditions that will reduce the size of the data to a reasonable fraction of your RAM. 2. Compute the `dask` result to get a `pandas` dataframe`.   2. On the resulting `pandas` dataframe query by the remaining conditions on each of your queries.

Comment: @Pedro-so one more thing,can i apply chunksize filtering(taking a chunk of dataframe like in the case of pandas dataframe,then doing some Op. then merging them --sending back ) on dask dataframe???

Comment: @Satya , that is exactly what dask is doing for you behind the scenes :)

Comment: @pedro-while """import dask.dataframe as dd""" i am getting an error ""AttributeError: type object 'Series' has no attribute 'dt'""" .Is there any module that should be imported before dask.COZ i have successfully installed dask and successfull in import dask??

Comment: Which pandas version are you running.  At the moment dask works best with 0.17.0

Comment: i ma using pandas version 0.16.o

Comment: Give it a shot with 0.17.0 (avoid 0.17.1, it has some threading bugs)

Comment: :is it not possible to create dask dataframe from a pickle file????i am getting an error like    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_pickle'

Comment: This post makes me want to try Dask. Neat! Thanks!